# До жути странный вопрос по PHP

Tags: php, массивы, yii2

Вообщем есть такая функция:

```
if ($sales['contract_is_signed'] == 0 || $sales['reklama_lk'] == 1) {
    return '';
} else {
    return Html::button('В корзину', [
        'class' => 'cart-list__item-price_button add-to-cart',
        'data-url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/add', 'slug' => $data->slug])
    ]);
}
```

Вроде все просто однако у меня в массиве $sales['contract_is_signed'] = 1, а она все равно выдаёт пустоту. Как или почему такое может быть ??
Проблема даже не только в таком сравнении даже если сравниваешь так:

```
if ($sales['contract_is_signed'] == 0) {
```

Один фиг выдаёт пустоту
Вот что показывает массив:

```
app\models\Manufacturer Object
(
[_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 40
        [created_at] => 1525270359
        [update_at] => 1529766272
        [name] => Тест
        [address_website] => 
        [logo] => 
        [user_id] => 46
        [contract_is_signed] => 1
        [reklama_lk] => 0
    )
```

Comment: ну значит `$sales['reklama_lk'] == 1`.  `||`- это ИЛИ

Comment: Нет, при выводе мой массив говорит, что $sales['contract_is_signed'] = 1, а это $sales['reklama_lk'] = 0 иначе я бы явно сюда не писал

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f6abd34ad3159b2275fa48630991159c0af3d57

Comment: Значит такая проблема ряда из ряда вон связана либо с сервером, либо еще с чем-то что я не знаю

Comment: Скорее всего с вашей невнимательностью

Comment: Приложите к вопросу вывод `var_dump($sales)` непосредственно перед этим `if`

Comment: что показывает var_dump($sales) ???

Comment: @n.osennij судя по концовке вопроса, вангую `var_dump` показывает, что `$sales['contract_is_signed']` равен нулю)

Comment: @Manitikyl Вы такое здесь пишите будто я пишу на php пару дней, и да с внимательностью у меня всё в порядке

Comment: @Moonwolf45 ну вы сами создали эту абсурдную ситуацию. Дело не в том, сколько вы пишите на пхп, а на сколько вы внимательны, такое со всеми бывает, но вы сами усугубляете ситуацию. Мы вам поможем, это главное :)

Comment: var_dump показывает что у вас вообще не массив. А объект (с arrayaccess интерфейсом). Выведите непосредственно значения `var_dump($sales['contract_is_signed'], $sales['reklama_lk'])`, возможно причина в реализации методов доступа

Comment: @Мелкий ну вроде уже видно, что не существует таких элементов. :<

Comment: покажите как вы вызываете функцию, `echo` там хоть используется?

Answer (score 0):

Не эксперт в `Yii`, но в `$sales` вы записываете результат запроса.

Например у вас там:

```
$sales = Sales::find()->...->one();
```

Нужно добавить `asArray()`, чтобы получилось типа такого:

```
$sales = Sales::find()->...->asArray()->one();
```

Comment: Я канечно попытался, но результат не изменился

Answer (score 0):

Если **var_dump** показывает что у вас объект, а не массив, то подозреваю что и обращаться нужно к полям объекта

```
if ($sales->contract_is_signed == 0 || $sales->reklama_lk == 1) {
    return '';
} else {
    return Html::button('В корзину', [
        'class' => 'cart-list__item-price_button add-to-cart',
        'data-url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/add', 'slug' => $data->slug])
    ]);
}
```